# Is there a way to specify the type of a class member based on the input type to a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am using a matrix library (Eigen) where the sizes of the matrices affect the type of the matrix. I am trying to create a class that is initialized with a constructor that takes a matrix and copies it over to the member matrix. Since this is a library, I would like to do this so that the user doesn't have to know the size of their matrix when they initialize my matrix class (because maybe their matrix is coming from another file)
Basically I would like something like the code below, where *unknownType* takes the form of *someType* upon being constructed

```
class Matrix{
  private: 
      unknownType m1;
  public:
      Matrix(someType m2): m1(m2){}
 };
```

Comment: Have you looked into templates? They are the solution to your problem.

Comment: what your code show is like template. but I guess you need *type erasure* technique?

Answer (score 0):

@BenSteffan is right.
It's what templates were made for.

Here is an absolutely toy example.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename ELEMENT_TYPE>
class Matrix {
    private:
        ELEMENT_TYPE element;
    public:
       Matrix(ELEMENT_TYPE value):element(value){}

       ELEMENT_TYPE get(){
           return element;
       }
};


int main() {
    Matrix<double> dmatrix(78.7);
    Matrix<int> imatrix(7000);

    std::cout<<dmatrix.get()<<' '<<imatrix.get()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the reason I wanted to avoid templates was because you still have to specify the type. I was wondering if there was a way to deduce the type based on the "value" variable that you use in the constructor above, as opposed to specifying <int> or <double> or <type> before every use of the constructor

Comment: That depends on how up to date your compiler is... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction